# How to extend the allocated memory of a bytebuffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I have a bytebuffer and I put Ints,Chars etc..
Because I do not know how much space I need I would like to dynamically growth the bytebuffer. How can this be done ?

Example :
- I have a Bytebuffer of 2 bytes
- I add a character to the bytebuffer (bytebuffer is full now )
- I like to add a Integer to the bytebuffer by extending the bytebuffer with 4 bytes. I can't allocate my bytebuffer with 6 bytes at start.

```
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);

    byteBuffer.putChar('a');
    byteBuffer.putInt(1);
```

---

I am very impressed, on how many people are working on my question that is some minutes old. Thank you all very much and thanks also to Stackoverflow, which is a great Plattform !

All of you asked, what I am doing. So I try to explain it here.
My usecase:
I have structured data represented as javaobjects (javaclasses) which I would like to store and read to/from a db. Reading should be very fast.
What I have done so far:

- java serialized and deserialized and stored it in a blob -> works well but too slow.
- tried several 3rd party serializer like kryo (which is very good), but not useable in my 
  case (android).

my new strategy :-) :
I do my own externalizing of my class. for that I would like to construct my entire data of my class sequential as an array of bytes. This can be slow. Then I store the bytearray to a blob in my db. When reading I would like to read the bytearray at once (bytearray is about 10k). (I will have a lot of them). Then parsing the bytearray to extract the structured data.

I thought using a bytebuffer is ideal for doing this, because of methods like putX and readX ? (X for chars, floats, int)

Comment: Why not use a different data structure? Why not use a linked list if you want dynamic reallocation?

Comment: Why can't you allocate a ByteBuffer with a capacity of 4 or 1024 bytes or 1 MB?

Comment: BTW putChar() is not used very often, it is likely that there is a better way to write characters depending on why you are doing this.

Comment: Your answers really doesn't help :-). Why do I ask for this, when I simply could allocate 1024 from beginning.

Comment: @user1344545 we are trying to understand why you are doing this.  If you want an alternative solution it would be useful to know what would be useful.

Comment: @user1344545 In that case the answer is; it depends on what you are trying to do.  There is many possible solutions. I have put in what is one amongst many.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Thanks for your help. I like to only use a bytebuffer, because tests in my case showed a very good performance. My case has to do with externalizing my classes, insteed of Java serializing. But I do not want to go to much into my usecase. Please let us concentrate on my questions regarding bytebuffer :-)

Comment: @user1344545 have you considered using a Shadow Array?

Comment: @user1344545 if you want performance and you want to write your data externally you want a direct buffer which is pre-alloated and reusable.  You can't re-size a ByteBuffer because there is no good reason you would want to.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Thanks for the hint. I do not know if I should do that, because it should run on a android device and I want to be inside the JVM, but I wiull check it. But with directbuffer the problem is the same to me.

Comment: @user1344545 The reason you use a direct buffer is that it is faster and uses less heap.  If neither of these matter, what does matter?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Perhabs I do not understand correct. A directbuffer I thought is outside of the JVM and reserves native memory ? In my Android app I like to be in the JVM. If something crashes , then only my app.

Comment: When you read or write a ByteBuffer at some point the data has to be written or read by a native method (which calls the OS).  At this point a heap ByteBuffer has to do a copy.  If you use a direct ByteBuffer from the start, you drop the need for this additional copy.  The JVM cannot allocate or touch memory outside the JVM unless the kernel allows you to (which I suspect it won't on a phone)

Comment: @user1344545 When you obtain a blob, can you read it straight from/to a ByteBuffer or is it a Stream? i.e. how can you access the data with a minimum of copies. ;)

Comment: or implement your own https://github.com/wjtxyz/VarSizedByteBuffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. This is by design. You can allocate a new byte buffer and write the overflowing data to that. You can keep the ByteBuffers in a LinkedList (which will grow as needed), and you can even spool off the old ones to disk, if you're running out of memory to allocate new ones. If each ByteBuffer is the same size, trivial equations will let you access it as if it where just the one buffer, but you lose the ability to use slicing or compacting, or any of the cool things you can do with one of those. :)

But like people have said over and over again, it depends on what you need it for.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the best answer is to make sure you have more than enough space from the start.  Having your ByteBuffer dynamically re-size is very expensive and much slower.

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(6 /* or more */);

byteBuffer.putChar('a');
byteBuffer.putInt(1);
```

---

The simplest buffer to use for characters is StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append('a');
sb.append('b');
```

> How would you add a new character after your last statement ?

```
sb.append('n');
```

Only when you are finished.

```
// if you need a ByteBuffer
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
// bb will have two bytes for 'a' and 'b'
```

However, if you are appending to a ByteBuffer (and not using chars) I would suggest making the buffer larger than you should ever need and thus you never need to resize it.  If you are concerned about using heap, you can use off heap instead.

```
// uses about 48 bytes of heap.
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024*1024);

bb.putInt(1234);
bb.putDouble(1.111);
bb.putLong(12345678987654321L);
```

Comment: +1 This is a much better solution because it allows for dynamic reallocation.

Comment: No thats not the soultion. How would you add a new character after your last statement ?

Comment: @user1344545 I have added another character in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts, but this is not useable for me :-) I extended me question to show, that appending to the stringbuffer doesn't help. I really want to allocate only 2 bytes at start and add Ints, Chars, Floats dynamically to the buffer.

Comment: I extended my example by changing the second put with an int.

Comment: @user1344545 If this is an imagined requirement instead of an actual requirement, your question may be unanswerable.  What is the actual reason you need to do this?  Why wouldn't you just preallocate a suitable buffer size from the start?

Comment: I extended my question to explain what I try to do.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using byte buffers is that you are starting with a fixed size. This is great if you know how much data you want to hold. For example, if you are reading input and you only want to read 12 bytes, then only create a 12-byte array.

If you don't know how much data you are going to have in a byte buffer, you can do 2 things:

1. If you need fast speed, then just allocate a large array based on a prediction of how much data you are going to need. For example, if you are reading in a large file and you want to read at fast speeds, then you should use a very large byte buffer (perhaps a couple of MB depending on the size of the file).
2. Use a structure that uses dynamic allocation. This is the much better solution, but it is slower. If you are allocating very large arrays, then this will be very slow, but it will not waste any memory. If you take a byte buffer and allocate 512 KB but you only use 1KB, that is a ton of wasted space! With dynamically allocated structures (LinkedList, Stack, Queue, Trees), you can add and remove elements as you need

The final solution, which is not recommended at all because it not only wastes a lot of memory, it is also slow. You can allocate as much space as you need in a byte buffer, then when you need more memory, create a new buffer and copy the data over. This is what you're trying to do and it will be very inefficient.

In my opionion, `Peter Lawrey`'s answer is an awesome solution to this problem just because you can easily go from a StringBuilder to a byte array. This has all of the efficiency and speed that you will need.

Comment: +1 BTW a `byte[]` of 2 bytes and a `byte[]` of 6 bytes uses the same amount of memory (on a 64-bit JVM).  You save nothing by making the size 2 instead of 6.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my usecase, which I would like to describe in short here. 
I accepted the answer of Mikkel, because regarding the question I guess it is the right answer, which also John mentoined. Also Thanks to Peter for the great explanations I could learn from.

I use DataInputStream, which is convenient for my situation. 
I create a stream of data based on my Javaobject with DataInputStream and the convenient methods like putInt,PutBoolean, PutString . Then I get the binaryarray of the DataInputStream amd store it as a blob to my db.

To reading is exactly the opposit way with DataInputStream.

With this I get a 500% better performance in reading the objects compared to javadeserialization of my javaobjects and a 25% less storage usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can, if You keep buffer instance in variable.
For example like this (kotlin):

```
fun ShortBuffer?.clone(addLimit: Int = 0): ShortBuffer? {
    if (this == null) {
        return ShortBuffer.allocate(addLimit)
    } else {
        val copy = ShortBuffer.allocate(this.limit() + addLimit)
        copy.put(this.array())
        return copy
    }
}

fun ShortBuffer?.safePut(shortArray: ShortArray?): ShortBuffer? {
    if (this == null) {
        if(shortArray == null) {
            return null
        } else {
            val ret = ShortBuffer.allocate(shortArray.size)
            ret.put(shortArray)
            return ret
        }
    } else if (shortArray == null) {
        return this
    } else if (this.remaining() < shortArray.size) {
        val ret = clone(shortArray.size-this.remaining())
        ret?.put(shortArray)
        return ret
    } else {
        this.put(shortArray)
        return this
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var buff = ShortBuffer.allocate(0)
buff = buff.safePut(shortArrayOf(1,2,3))
```